# Carbon locale format and decline

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

How I can set locale to carbon with format?
I have date:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
Carbon::setLocale('ru');
$dt = Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%d %M');
```

I Get Month with:

> 25 декабрь

How I can get locale with decline? Example:

> 25 декабря

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on an English example?

Comment: Yes. 25 december => 25th of December. How I can Get: "25th of December" with locale? My locale is ru.

Comment: Nominative case for months it's normal if you want genitive case You can modify ru_RU locale which is placed by path: /usr/share/i18n/locales/ru_RU. There is section **mon** (You can change last character for each month) but I guess it's not the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

I've just [tested it](http://prntscr.com/hs6yia) and this will return `25 декабря`:

```
Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%d %B');
```

In comments, you've said you have trouble with the date. Try this fix, from the Carbon Docs:

> on Linux
>   If you have trouble with translations, check locales installed in your system (local and production).
>
> locale -a to list locales enabled.
>
> sudo locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8 to install a new locale.
>
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales to publish all locale enabled.
>
> And reboot your system.

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: :( Not working for me. You passed setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')?

Comment: @Jajaja yes, I've used your code, but with `%B`. It works perfectly in Tinker.

Comment: Hm. I Get 25 декабрь. May be in system debian error? I use debian.

Comment: @Jajaja in Carbon docs there is a fix for `formatLocalized()` method for Linux systems. Try it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Jajaja sorry, can't help you with that because I don't use Debian. If no one else will be able to help you here, you can ask this question in VK Laravel group or on laravel.ru. I'm sure folks from the Russian community will help you to solve the problem.

Comment: What os you have? Where tested script.

Comment: @Jajaja Mac Os X

Comment: But can you do test on centos or debian?

Comment: @Jajaja I have only production LInux setup and I don't want to install OS on my home comuter just to check this, sorry. As I said before, you can ask the same question to Russian Laravel community. There are thousands of guys who use Linux.