# Localize Date using Carbon in .blade template

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-blade, php-carbon

I formatted the date using Carbon in my `.blade` template like this:

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($event['date_from'])->toFormattedDateString() }}
```

**And it outputs:**

```
Mar 20, 2018
```

So, how to localize the date to for example Russian format:

Comment: you may use Carbon::setLocale('ru'); for more info visit : http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972040/1227923

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Is that example for `.blade` templates? Not for Controllers...

Comment: @КамиловТимур you can do this anywhere in your app, but it's a good idea to set the locale in a middleware or a controller and then use `toFormattedDateString()` in a blade template.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin can you please show me how to do that? Cz I tried to add the lines to Controller and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @КамиловТимур the old answer has a [link to an example](http://prntscr.com/hs6yia). If this doesn't work, follow the instructions (the yellow block) in the [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972040/1227923).

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin this is the way I set the locale: `public function index()
    {        
        Carbon::setLocale('ru');
        $events = Event::all();
        $tickets = Ticket::all();
        return view('pages.events.index')->with([ 'events'  => $events, 'tickets' => $tickets ]);
    }`

Comment: @КамиловТимур you're not using the code I've shown, but Prashant's code. So I think you should ask him this question.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `Carbon::setLocale('ru');` & `formatLocalized('%d %M');`

for more info visit : [Carbon localization](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization)

Comment: I need to localize the date in `.blade`. Is it possible?

Comment: writing a logic in blade is not a good coding so i will suggest you to write localize logic in controller then pass it to blade file

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel blade templates, I set up a new function off my model:

```
public function localizedDiffForHumans() {
    Carbon::setLocale(App::getLocale());
    return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
}
```

And then just replace the call from the template:

```
{{$message->localizedDiffForHumans()}}
```